# R-waterfall diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2, waterfall

when I try to create a waterfall with  the following data, I take the following error. appreciate your support..

Below is the data:

[image]

And this is the code and error:

[image]

Comment: Please provide data with `dput()` function.

Comment: You should remove `x` argument from `geom_rect`. You can add `desc` with `geom_text`.

Comment: @pawel Chabros, I still  get error, can you please explain. I replace geom_rect with geom_text and removed X arg.

Comment: Do not replace `geom_rect` with `geom_text`. Just remove `x` argument. I said you can add `desc` column with `geom_text` separately.

Comment: @PawełChabros thanks a lot :))

Comment: @PawełChabros if I also wanna add labels on top of bars, I am adding the following as well. +geom_text(position = 'identity', stat ='amount') .However, it did not work

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now it includes giving a x-scale labels based on `desc` column. With `geom_text()` you can add labels anywhere in the plot, but you have to specify mapping through `aes()` function.

Comment: @PawełChabros it worked, thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(wrapr)

deneme %.>%
  ggplot(., aes(
    xmin = id - .45,
    xmax = id + .45,
    ymin = end,
    ymax = start,
    fill = type
  )) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = .$id,
    labels = .$desc
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: @ Pawel Chabros,it works thanks

Comment: Can you accept my answer? :)